# iPhone app crash when registering for push notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, swift4, registration

I am finalizing an IOS app (xcode9, swift 4) using pushpad. When the app installs it asks the user to register "Notifications", then runs NetworkService: PushNotificationsNetworkable and more specifically :

```
self.networkRequest(request, session: self.session) { (response) in 
    switch response { 
        case .Success(let data): 
           guard let device = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Device.self, from: data) else {   
               return 
           } 
//crashes here 
       completion(device.id, true) 


        case .Failure(let data): 
             guard (try? JSONDecoder().decode(Reason.self, from: data)) != nil else { return } 
            completion(nil, false) 
    } 
}
```

the app crash every time (where it is marked "crash here above"). I then get the following message:

## 1  0x0000000106a0a260 in closure #1 in Pods/PushNotifications/Sources/NetworkService.swift:25

Can you give me any advice?

Comment: I looks like `completion` is nil. Or `device.id` is non-optional in `completion` definition but was nil. Did you check it?

Comment: Completion handles nil since the failure case explicitly sends nil